# Finding decimal in a line in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a file with multiple lines like these:

```
hello check2check number 1235.67 thanks[4]
also 67907 another number of interest[45]
```

I am trying to find these numbers (float) in each line (they exist only once per line) but the last string might have integers in square brackets or an integer might exist before (as in check2check shown above)

```
1235.67
67907
```

```
import re

def updates (self, fileHandler,spec):
   for line in fileHandler:
      line_new = line.strip('\n')
      ll = line_new.split()
      l = len(ll)


   for i in range (l-1): 
            delay = re.search('\d*\.?\d+',i)
```

I keep getting this error:

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Is this the correct way to look for the numerical values?

Comment: `i` is an integer.  You're trying to treat it like a string.  Don't do this character by character.  Just search the entire line for `re.search( r'\d+(\.\d+)?', line)`

Answer (score 2):

This `for i in range (l-1)` iterates over integers.

Use

```py
for line in fileHandler:
  match = re.search(r'(?<!\S)\d*\.?\d+(?!\S)', line)
  if match:
    print(match.group())
```

In your class:

```py
def updates (self, fileHandler, spec):
    results = []
    for line in fileHandler:
        match = re.search(r'(?<!\S)\d*\.?\d+(?!\S)', line)
        if match:
            results.append(match.group())
    return results
```

Remove `spec` if not needed.

Answer (score 2):

One approach could apply

- a regex matching numbers (`(?<= |^)\d+(\.\d+)?(?= |$)`) in your string, using [`re.findall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) method
- the cast of each value to the float type, using Python built-in [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function

on each of your string by iterating using a list comprehension.

```
import re

def updates (self, fileHandler,spec):
    return [map(float, re.findall('(?<= |^)\d+(\.\d+)?(?= |$)', line)[0]) for line in fileHandler]
```

Comment: What is s2 here? Thanks! I am new to python so still learning

Comment: Nevermind, forgot my variable for testing in there, you really should use `line`.